# App.listen on an already running port of shared hosting

Tags: node.js, express, backend, shared-hosting

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    console.log("running on that weird path i made///");
    res.send("HELLO THIS IS A WEBPAGE TRYOUT!");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server running on 3000");
})
```

I’m trying to create a simple app (for practice) which does a simple hello world. Using express via node.js
I can do it locally no problems.
The problem is I’m trying to run it on an existing server using cPanel shared hosting.
And there is obviously an already running domain name(and has website installed in Wordpress), so I cannot do a simple app.listen to a port which is obviously already running. And I’m guessing therefor I cannot do app.get(“/“....)

I’ve tried a different port-but the get request won’t work(I think obviously since that’s not the one running?)
So when I tell it to listen to the cPanel port, it throws an error that it’s already running.
And I don’t want to stop from the website to run. Is there a way to work this?
Tried also using subdomains. Same result.

Edit:
this worked on postman, when I've sent a get request to that address. tried port 3000, and it showed my res.send on the postman tab.

Edit2:
I've solved this...i forgot to put :3000 on the address..
as in [www.example.com:3000](http://www.example.com:3000)
this doesn't work if i don't add the :3000.
and also if i do process.env.PORT and .IP..guessing its because its a shared hosting, or because wordpress is installed...

I won't delete just in case anyone did the same mistake as me.

Comment: cpanel is delivered by apache or nginx running on port 80 and I guess its not possible to get other ports in shared hosting ,you have to try vps or heroku

Answer (score 0):

If the problem that the port is already in use, you may try to use `0` as a port that will cause it to take a random free port on the machine.

```
const server = app.listen(0, function(){
    console.log(`Server is listening on http://localhost:${server.address().port}`);
})
```